# Electroporation of one-cell embryo?

Tags: molecular-biology

Would electroporation be successful on a one/two-celled mouse embryo? If it would, what buffer could be used and what percentage of cells would be viable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffers are usually supplied with the electroporation instrument; at least Lonza provides buffers for different types of cells. Single cell electroporation techniques exist, but they have been mostly done on neurons.<sup>[[1](http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v4/n6/abs/nprot.2009.56.html),[2](http://www.jove.com/video/705/single-cell-electroporation-in-vivo-within-the-intact-developing-brain)]</sup>

You can also try microinjection but it requires some practice. [This](http://www.nature.com/srep/2014/140624/srep05417/full/srep05417.html) study reports a transfection agent called VisuFect which can be used for zygotes as well.

I am not very sure about the success rate (AFAIK it is not that good) but I think it is anyway risky with organisms which do not produce a lot of embryos.